# Nothing happening after clicking open folder in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

Just on one project that i have cloned, from Intellij i choose open/import project, choose the folder then nothing happens, no error message or anything to go on. The project is a typescript SAM project. Thanks

Comment: Please check idea.log (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085-Locating-IDE-log-files) for errors/warnings

Answer (score 0):

Was able to do it when choosing create project from existing sources then choosing the folder